# Using apache httpclient, how to you trust invalid certs only for the proxy side of the connection?

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

In apache httpclient, is there a way to ignore the only the certificate from the proxy, but verify the certificate from the destination. Or is something only configured inside the proxy?

I want to ignore the certificate issues only for the connection to the proxy. For the connection from the proxy to destination, I want the certificates to be validated. To make a bit more clear I created this ASCII art:

```
              Trust             Reject
              invalid           invalid
              certs             certs
   ---------          -------            ----------------
  | MyServer|   ---> | Proxy |   --->   | Destination    |
   ---------          -------           | ex: google.com |
                                         ----------------
```

Note this is different from all the existing questions that ask to trust self signed certificates because they ask about trusting self signed certificates but do not request separating the trust between proxy and destination. Their solutions are of the pattern:

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
  .loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> true)
  .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
  sslContext,
  NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
  .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
  .build();
```

I believe this should be possible because the command line tool `curl` provides separate options for the proxy part of the connection and the real connection (taken from the `curl` man page:

```
       -k, --insecure
              (TLS SFTP SCP) By default, every secure connection curl makes is verified to be secure before the transfer takes place. This option makes curl skip the verification step and proceed without checking.

              When this option is not used for protocols using TLS, curl verifies the server's TLS certificate before it continues: that the certificate contains the right name which matches the host name used in the URL and that the
              certificate has been signed by a CA certificate present in the cert store.  See this online resource for further details:
               https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

              For SFTP and SCP, this option makes curl skip the known_hosts verification.  known_hosts is a file normally stored in the user's home directory in the ".ssh" subdirectory, which contains host names and their public keys.

              WARNING: using this option makes the transfer insecure.

              When curl uses secure protocols it trusts responses and allows for example HSTS and Alt-Svc information to be stored and used subsequently. Using -k, --insecure can make curl trust and use such information from malicious
              servers.

              Providing -k, --insecure multiple times has no extra effect.  Disable it again with --no-insecure.

              Example:
               curl --insecure https://example.com

              See also --proxy-insecure, --cacert and --capath.

       --proxy-insecure
              Same as -k, --insecure but used in HTTPS proxy context.

              Providing --proxy-insecure multiple times has no extra effect.  Disable it again with --no-proxy-insecure.

              Example:
               curl --proxy-insecure -x https://proxy https://example.com

              See also -x, --proxy and -k, --insecure. Added in 7.52.0.
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding and the verification of the certificate of the destination can only be configure on the proxy? This was my initial assumption until I noticed curl had two separate options.

Comment: yes, you can send secure requests to the proxy, where you'll do a handshake with the proxy first.  Then a tunnel is opened where your secure request to the web site will be  tunneled through the proxy.  (handshake is between you and the web site, proxy just passes all that along)  So when you set the proxy to be insecure, it'll ignore insecure certs in your handshake between you and the proxy.  That should have no effect on the handshake between you and the web site.

Comment: You should be able to do curl --trace to see the handshakes: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-ascii

Comment: I'm looking for java code using apache httpclient on how to do this. currently all the samples i found haven't done it.

Comment: ahh, it looks a bit ugly in there... I think you need to create/set a different SSLContext for proxy.  If you just don't set it for HttpClient it'll have the default context which should be secure.

Comment: I think it'll be much easier to just use http for the proxy.

Comment: For the proxy, the library only exposes HttpHost for me to manipulate.